# How to dynamically re-sample M4A file in ObjectC

Tags: ios, iphone, core-audio, m4a

I want to take dynamically a song from iTunes and re-sample it to some lower quality rate.

I'm able to import the song from iTunes, but I don't know how to re-sample from 320KBit (supposed that iTunes work at this quality) to 96KBit and keep the M4A format (**very important, I don't want to use MP3**).

Comment: I don't know if there's any standard framework to do it with, if not you can always try to find any 3rd party solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an audio library that can convert audio easily.
You set the sample rate, channel number, and other properties that you want.

Here's the URL:
https://github.com/lixing123/ExtAudioConverter